# Give prefix to classes of an external library

Tags: java, class

I'm using an external library in which many classes have same name as mine (`Route`, `Waypoint`, etc...). To have not any kind of mess or confusion, I would like to give a prefix to external library classes (e.g.: `extLib_Route`, `extLib_Waypoint`, etc..).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Well the prefix is the package name.

Comment: You'll have to use the qualified package name, e.g. `com.yourcompany.Route` etc

Comment: tank you people, I wished a shorter name, but first of all I have to learn how things can be well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, in fact quite possibly the only option, would be to refer to those external classes using the fully qualified package name, e.g.

```
com.some.library.Route
```

As opposed to your class `Route`, which would not have a prefix, because either it is the same package as the Java class using it, or you have an import statement for it already.

Technically speaking, a class with the fully qualified package name does have a prefix, so maybe this will fit your needs.

Comment: I tried to do this. (as you suggested, my classes are into my package) But Android Studio rename my classes instead of corresponding ones of library. I was thinking about a such solution, but I wished a prefix instead of such lengthy ones given by library-long-name :)

Comment: Remove the import statements for the library, and then drop in the fully qualified package name when you declare it.  This is an import war in IntelliJ.  I can't remember what tricks you can use to workaround it.

Comment: If you don't remember other trick, maybe I would use fully package names as everyone else, and learn as people usually do.